Given a sine and cosine function that define a circle with radius 1, is there a way to generate a corresponding distance function?
I'm aware that there is a branch of math about this, but I don't quite remember the name.
I was thinking about this because I was messing with the functions $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{\sin(xn^2+t)}{n^2})$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{\cos(xn^2+t)}{n^2})$ and was wondering if you could derive a geometry that used a distance function that when given the equation $distance((x,y),(0,0))$ would output the same circle as if you used the above sine and cosine functions.

Are you referring to Analytical Geometry?
